# Wrapping py_binary with arguments

Tags: bazel

A package `//foo` has a `py_binary`:

```
py_binary(
  name = "foo",
  srcs = ["foo.py"],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

`foo.py` accepts 2 positional commandline arguments.

Now in a package `//bar` I would like to create an "alias" for invoking `foo` binary with certain arguments.

The following sadly does not work:

```
py_binary(
  name = "bar",
  deps = [
    "//foo:foo",
  ],
  args = [
    "$(location first_file)",
    "$(location second_file)",
  ],
  data = [
    ":first_file",
    ":second_file",
  ],
)
```

The problem is that `py_binary` wants a main src file in the current package. Is there a other or better to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by creating a `//foo:bind.bzl`:

```
def bind_foo(name, **kwargs):
    copy_file(
        name = "%s.py.create" % name,
        src = "//foo:foo.py",
        dst = "%s.py" % name, # Appease local main search
    ) # Why is no copy_file action provided by Skylark???

    py_binary(
        name = name,
        srcs = [
            "%s.py" % name,
        ],
        deps = [
            "//foo:foo",
        ],
        **kwargs
    )
```

Which in `//bar` I can simply use:

```
load("//foo:bind.bzl", "bind_foo")

bind_foo(
    name = "bar",
    args = [
        "$(location first_file)",
        "$(location second_file)",
    ],
    data = [
        ":first_file",
        ":second_file",
    ],
)
```

This also makes the whole thing more expressive, so yay :)

Comment: I tried to implement your solution. However, bazel complains that "//foo:foo.py" is not a visible target from //bar. I suspect that this depends on the implementation of the copy_file rule. I used the bazel-skylib rule https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/master/rules/private/copy_file_private.bzl . Did you use a custom rule?

Comment: This is 2 years old. The py rules have been revamped AFAIK. Currently do not use Bazel + Python, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [`main`](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/python.html#py_binary.main) attribute, e.g.:

```
py_binary(
  name = "bar",
  main = "//foo:foo.py",
  srcs = ["//foo:foo"],
...
```

Note that this means you have to expose foo.py in foo/BUILD:

```
exports_files(["foo.py"])
```

Comment: AFAIT `main` disregards all package info and searches for the rel target only.

Comment: If so, I think that's a bug.